# SSL SOCKET JAVA

Tags: java, socket

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio que haga lo siguiente:

> Establecer conexión entre Servidor y Cliente mediante socket SSL. Lo
>   primero que hacen es presentarse y comprueban que son de confianza
>   mediante certificados que he realizado con Keytool de java. ( Uno para
>   el certificado y otro para el servidor )

Y por ahora tengo esto:

```
public class SSLClient {

    //aquí heu de ficar les vostres dades
 private static String CLAU_CLIENT = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_161\\bin\\client_ks";
 private static String CLAU_CLIENT_PASSWORD = "456456";



 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Estableix la key store per validar el certificat del servidor.

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", CLAU_CLIENT);
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", CLAU_CLIENT_PASSWORD);

  try{
      SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
      SSLSocket CliSocket =(SSLSocket) sslFactory.createSocket("localhost", 4043);

       Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);      
      PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(CliSocket.getOutputStream());

      System.out.println("Deja una linea blanca para acabar:");
      String text = reader.nextLine();
      while (!text.equals("")) {
        writer.println(text);
        writer.flush();
        text = reader.nextLine();
      }
      writer.println("<<FI>>");
      writer.flush();
      CliSocket.close();      
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error en les comuncacions: " + ex);
    }
    }
 }




 //private Socket clienteSinCertificado() throws Exception {

 //}

 //private Socket clienteConCertificado() throws Exception {

 //}
//}
```

CLASE SERVIDOR

```
public class SSLServer extends Thread {
 private Socket socket;

 public SSLServer(Socket socket) {
  this.socket = socket;
 }



 private static String SERVIDOR_CLAU = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_161\\bin\\server_ks";
 private static String SERVIDOR_CLAU_PASSWORD = "123123";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", SERVIDOR_CLAU);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", SERVIDOR_CLAU_PASSWORD);


     try {
      SSLServerSocketFactory sslFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
      SSLServerSocket srvSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslFactory.createServerSocket(4043);
      new SSLServer(srvSocket.accept()).start();
      int numClient = 1;

      while (true) {
        SSLSocket CliSocket = (SSLSocket) srvSocket.accept();

        Scanner reader = new Scanner (CliSocket.getInputStream());      

        String text = reader.nextLine();
        while (!text.equals("<<FIN>>")) {
          System.out.println("[Client " +numClient + "] " + text);
          System.out.flush();
          text = reader.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("[Client " +numClient + "] cerrando conexión...");
        CliSocket.close();
        numClient++;
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error en las comunicaciones: " + ex);
    }

  }

 public void run() {
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
      String data = br.readLine();
      pw.println("Conectando");
      pw.close();
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
 }

}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Error en les comuncacions: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect
>
> java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
>   Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider:
>   SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)    at
>   javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:160)
>     at
>   javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:173)
>     at ioc.dam.m9.uf1.eac3.b2.SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:53) Caused
>   by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
>   implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)    at
>   java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1617)    at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)    at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)    at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)     at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)   at
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:113)
>     at ioc.dam.m9.uf1.eac3.b2.SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:52) Caused
>   by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server_ks (El sistema no puede encontrar
>   la ruta especificada)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getKeyManagers(SSLContextImpl.java:822)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.(SSLContextImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.(SSLContextImpl.java:913)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1595)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server_ks (El sistema no puede encontrar
>   la ruta especificada)     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder$2.run(SSLContextImpl.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder$2.run(SSLContextImpl.java:823)
>     ... 15 more

Estoy bastante perdida con el tema y quizás tengo algunas cosas mal.. pero ya no sé que más hacer :(

gracias!

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías por favor, poner una traza de error más completa? Es necesario para ver la causa. :) En vez de imprimir el mensaje definido por tí (Error en las comunicaciones), usa `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Solo me pone eso no me da ningún error más ni más texto que poder poner lo siento :(

Comment: Ya actualicé el comentario.

Comment: editado con el error

Comment: El error es por Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server_ks, no está encontrando el archivo, revisa los privilegios con los que corre la máquina virtual de java, verifica la ruta, que dice la documentación en que debes colocar la carpeta o el nombre del fichero como tal?. saludos!

Comment: Fijate además que el error indica PrivilegedActionException así que me parece que es porque no tiene permiso de lectura el usuario de la JVM sobre ése archivo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora, el error está en que no logra encontrar el keystore que indicas en la ruta.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server_ks

Revisa que el nombre del keystore sea `server.ks` y no, por ejemplo, `server.jks`, que suele ser la extensión usada para los keystores.

Si eso no funciona, revisa entonces que no sea por los espacios en la ruta al archivo (Java odia los espacios en los nombres jeje). Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639285/spaces-in-java-file-path-to-an-executable) de SO en inglés y [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243993/how-to-execute-command-line-exe-file-in-java) para ver opciones.

Comment: no .. :( mi fichero se llama server_ks

Comment: Y sobre la forma de crear la ruta al archivo?

Comment: Tampoco.. no sé que puede ser :(

Comment: Pues es claro que el problema es que no encuentra el archivo en esa ruta. Hay que revisar por qué.